# Can I query DynamoDB for documents with empty objects

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to query Dynamodb for all documents in given partition key in witch certain sub document is empty? That is, it is an empty object.
I have documents that look something like following:

```
{
    bag : 'some_id',
    secondary: 'up',
    books : {
        one : {
            title : 'Some Title'
        }
    }
},
{
    bag : 'some_id',
    secondary: 'down',
    books : {}
}
```

In MongoDB it would be query for '{ books : {}}'. It is a simple question but I can not find the answer in the docks and as far as I can tell, that query is not possible through AWS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dynamodb AWS SDK doesn't support this query. When you use ":books":{"M":{}}, you would get "Query key condition not supported" error message.